# How to set variable from a specific string in a text file in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I need to be able to set a variable using a string from a text file, for example if the text file contents looks like:

```
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Wi-Fi
Disabled       Disconnected   Dedicated        Local Area connection
```

Which can be found using:

```
netsh int show int | clip
```

and pasting it into a text file.

I need to be able to use whatever word there is at the position "Wi-Fi" is at, as a variable. The word I have to use can be identified as being on the line that has "Enabled" on it and in the column of "Interface Name" or the fourth string in the line.
I cannot use

```
set INTERFACE=Wi-Fi
```

because when I ran the script on a different computer they had a different interface name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'm using Windows 10. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch to find a string of numbers from tsv or text file and put it into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851464/batch-to-find-a-string-of-numbers-from-tsv-or-text-file-and-put-it-into-a-variab) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15537321/62576

Comment: Had a little problem with the writing the drive path into the code as each computer would have a different drive path to the text file. TessallatingHeckler's answer works without needing a txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on Windows 10, you have PowerShell 5. *Ten years* of post-batch-file progress. Any help appreciated? How about a push to not use batch files?

```
$interface = (Get-NetAdapter |Where Status -eq Up)[0].Name
```

It's really nice not to be abusing a `for` loop to mangle text to get anything done. Which, I guess, would look something like:

```
@echo off
rem allow the variable check to work properly in the loop
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem clear the interface value
SET INTERFACE=

rem loop over netsh output lines, searching
rem for lines which start "Enabled" and splitting by spaces
for /f "tokens=3,* delims= " %%A in ('netsh int show int^|findstr "^Enabled"') do (

    # update interface with the first one, not for the rest
    # or it will always end up as the last one
    if "!INTERFACE!"=="" (set INTERFACE=%%B)
)
```

Edit: corrected with findstr addition, from @dbenham.

Comment: Your batch code is almost correct. However, you need to locate the line(s) where the state is enabled - you cannot rely on it being the first non-header line. You can use FINDSTR, and then you don't need the skip option: `in ('netsh int show int^|findstr "^Enabled"')`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I'll look into PowerShell 5 thanks for the tip, could you briefly explain what the %%A is? I'm new to batch and coding in general.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Oop forgot to add that your code works beautifully except that it adds a space after wifi, %INTERFACE% should equal "Wi-Fi" and not "Wi-Fi ". Not sure how to fix it. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: `%%A` is the for loop variable - it becomes each line of text from `netsh`. Yes, it can only be a single character. Yes it's `%` sometimes and `%%` other times. Yes it magically translates into `%%B` by combining `delims= ` (which sets the delimiter to a single space, because it can only be one character), that means it splits strings like "Local Area Connection" up as well - but `tokens=3,*` makes `%%A` become the 3rd thing from the split string, and the next letter `%%B` becomes the fourth-and-rest things. Lucky the interface name was the last thing on the line. Oops, will edit and  fix.